# Doctrine query delete

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've got an error that I don't understand with a doctrine query.
I try to delete every entry with certain id with this :

```
$qb = $this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder();
                $query = $qb
                ->delete('route', 'r')
                ->where("r.user_id = 423")
                ->getQuery();

                $query->execute();
```

When I execute this one I've got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message 'DELETE route r WHERE r.user_id = 423' in
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('DELETE route r ...') #1
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(854):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Class 'route' i...',
>   Array) #2
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1132):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->AbstractSchemaName() #3
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(788):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->DeleteClause() #4
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(734):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->DeleteStatement() #5
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(229):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->QueryLanguage() #6 /var/ in
>   /var/www/mywebsite/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on line 49

I don't understand the meaning of this error.
Thanks to anyone who can lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of the stack-trace seems to suggest that there is something worng with the classname.

```
...semanticalError('Class 'route' i...', Array)
```

Are you sure you are correctly specifying the entity name? You should be using a fully qualified classname which includes the namespace.

Example: `DELETE MyProject\Model\Route r WHERE r.user_id = 4`

**Solutions:**

**I.** Just in case checks:

1. Make sure the class name is correct. Both the case and namespace + classname.
2. Run `composer dump-autoload` to make sure your classes are properly loaded.
3. Make sure your entity exists and is properly mapped.

**II.** Use Doctrine's EntityManager remove method instead.

Example:

```
$em = new EntityManager();
$route= $em->find('route', 1);
$em->remove($route);
$em->flush();
```